# If $n<0$ assume $f(x) \not = 0$. Prove that $(f^n)^\prime(x)=n(f(x))^{n-1}$.

Tags: real-analysis, chain-rule

Question: Let $f: I \rightarrow R$ be differentiable. Given $n \in Z$, define $f^n$ be the function defined by $f^n(x)= (f(x))^n$. If $n<0$ assume $f(x) \not = 0$. Prove that $(f^n)^\prime(x)=n(f(x))^{n-1}$.

Let $g: S \rightarrow R$ defined by $g(y) = y^n$ for $n<0$. if I can show that 
$g$ is differentiable, then  I can prove $(f^n)^\prime(x)=n(f(x))^{n-1}$ by using the chain rule.

I saw one solution to prove $g$ is differentiable, using [binomial theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756735/show-that-the-difference-quotient-of-1-xn-exists), and I am wondering if there is another way to prove this without using binomial theorem since I haven't seen this in my course.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You really want $(f^n)'(x) = n f(x)^{n-1} f'(x)$ using Chain Rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that $f(x) = x^n$ is differentiable, you just need to know that products of differentiable functions are differentiable. This follows from the product rule. For a quick proof:

\begin{align}
\lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h) - f(x)g(x)}{h}} & = \lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{f(x+h)g(x+h) - f(x)g(x+h) + f(x)g(x+h) - f(x)g(x)}{h}} \\
& = \lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}g(x+h)}+\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h}g(x)} \\
& = f'(x)g(x)+g'(x)f(x)
\end{align}

Then since $h(x)=x$ is differentiable, by induction so is $g(x)=x^n$ as the $n$-fold product of $h$.

Then apply Chain Rule to the composition $g \circ f$ to get 
$$(g\circ f)' = f' \cdot (g'\circ f)$$
or in other words
$$(f^n)'(x) = f'(x)\cdot n f(x)^{n-1}$$

Comment: how can I use the induction when $n<0$?

Comment: take the inverse of the function and that will make $n>0$.

Comment: In that case, you can let $h(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and show directly that this is differentiable (by just computing it using the limit definition). Then if we write $g_n(x) = x^n$, we can replace $g_n$ with $h \circ g_{-n}$ to consider the case where $n>0$. Of course, we'll need to account for that in the application of the Chain Rule

Comment: If I take the inverse of $x$, then it is $\frac 1x$, which is not differentiable at 0.

Comment: Yes, and there's nothing that will change that. If you want to consider the case where $n<0$, then you'll need to require that $f(x) \neq 0$ for any $x$ you're considering.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f^n(a+h)-f^n(a)}{h}= \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{(f(a+h)-f(a)
) \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f^{i}(a+h)f^{n-i}(a)}{h} \\ = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f^n(a+h)-f^n(a)}{h}\cdot\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f^{i}(a+h)f^{n-i}(a) \\ =f'(a)\cdot n f^{n-1}(a)$$

Here we use the identity $$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+ba^{n-2}+b^2a^{n-3}\cdots+b^{n-1})$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

You are composing $a(x) = 1/x$ and $b(x) = x^n$.

Answer (score 0):

$$ g:x \mapsto f^n(x)$$ is the composition of $$ f $$ by $$ x \mapsto x^n $$

You should know the derivative of a composition of two functions?

Other method: by induction.

Edit: didn't see you wanted to prove the expression of the derivative of $$ x \mapsto x^n $$
I suggest you use induction then.